# Does Blender 2.8 require microsoft access database 2010 to run?

Tags: linked-data

Contemplating deleting 'microsoft access database 2010'. Does Blender use this as a database?

Comment: It's not one of Blender's dependencies.

Comment: Many thanks. The reason I asked is due to MAD 2010 appearing exactly the same day I installed Blender. Process of ilimination. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Blender is built on open technologies which are also available on non-microsoft platforms.  Therefore it cannot depend on anything more than a basic install of Windows and of course, relevant graphics drivers.

Comment: Many thanks. The reason I asked is due to MAD 2010 appearing exactly the same day I installed Blender. Process of ilimination. 

Comment: No problem, please mark as accepted answer so others know that the problem is resolved.  You can also check the installed date/time of MS Access to assist in your search of the culprit.  Also remember only to install software from the official blender.org website.